# Mean and covariance estimators for indirect (transformed) observations of Gaussian

Tags: estimators, multivariate-normal-distribution, inverse-problem

Suppose we have a multivariate Gaussian random variable $\mathbf{x}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, and $n$ measurements $\mathbf{y}_1 = H_1 \mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{y}_2 = H_2 \mathbf{x}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n = H_n\mathbf{x}_n$, where the $\mathbf{x}_i$ are IID realizations of $\mathbf{x}$, and the $H_i$ are known matrices (let's call them measurement matrices or observation operators), possibly non-invertible, non-square, and of different sizes.

We do not know $\mathbf{\mu}$ or $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. How could one estimate them based on the indirect observations $\{\mathbf{y}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{y}_n\}$? I know there are some solutions for special cases, trivially when the $H_i$ are identity (in which case one could just use the standard sample mean and covariance) or when the $H_i$ act to remove some elements of $\mathbf{x}$ (in which case it is a missing data problem). Is there a solution for general $H_i$?

Comment: Provided the problem is identifiable, maximum likelihood will work.  After all, the set of measurements has a multivariate Normal distribution.  Thus, this comes down to a constrained quadratic optimization.

Comment: Thank you! That's very straightforward.